# Как сделать тепловой след от курсора

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-animation

Не могу понять, как сделать такой же тепловой след от курсора
[тепловой след появляется на верхнем блоке](https://ceremonycoffee.com/color/)

Comment: **https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/**. Спасибо.

Comment: Самое прикольное, что в ответах предложили использовать блоки.. Даже не смотрели как на сайте реализовано ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 8):

Немного если сократить код и нагрузку на браузер и выбрасывать за собой мусор, получится вот так)

```js
$('html').on('mousemove', function(e){
  var bubble = $('<div class="bubble"></div>');
  bubble.css({'left': e.clientX-50, 'top': e.clientY-50});
  $('body').append(bubble);
  setInterval(function(){bubble.remove()}, 1000)
});
```

```css
.bubble{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: coral;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 coral;
  animation: leave 1s ease forwards;
}
@keyframes leave{
  from{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  to{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

С положением думаю разберешься как до курсора подвинуть)
И нужно сетинтервалом удалять их а то будут апендиться бесконечно) ДОМ тоже чистить надо)
Надеюсь идея понятна)

```js
$('html').on('mousemove', function(e){
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  var id = new Date();
  var sec = id.getSeconds();
  var min = id.getMinutes();
  var ms = id.getMilliseconds();
  var all = min+''+sec+''+ms;
  $('body').append('<div id='+all+' class="bubble"></div>');
  $('#'+all+'').css({'left': x, 'top': y});
});
```

```css
.bubble{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: coral;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 coral;
  animation: leave 1s ease forwards;
}
@keyframes leave{
  from{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  to{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: а не проще тогда `var all = Date.now()`?) а лучше сам бабл без id в переменную сразу

Comment: красивее чем на примере получилось))

Comment: Пожалуйста, рефакторите как будет удобно) Я с такими вещами никогда не сталкивался, набросал на скорую руку. Просто для общего развития. тут в идеале вобще переменных можно не плодить. Но я поставил себе цель не сделать за кого то, а подать направление для размышления.