# Как сделать след от курсора?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, css-animation, jquery-ui

Хочу сделать на сайте след от курсора, подобный как на этом https://jacekjeznach.com/, но не знаю с чего начать и как это реализовать, используя canvas, или что-то другое.

Подобный вопрос уже был задан [Как сделать тепловой след от курсора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/874928/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0), но там не то решение, которое мне нужно. Там в ответах предложили использовать блоки, это не то.
Мне нужно реализовать похожий эффект, как на сайте, что я скинул, но не могу понять как

Comment: _но там не то решение, которое мне нужно._ - а какое решение тебе нужно?

Comment: Добавь это в вопрос.

Comment: можешь взять их скритп [osciliator.js](https://jacekjeznach.com/wp-content/themes/new/js/vendor/osciliator.js)

Answer (score 0):

Похожий вопрос и готовое решение отсюда:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position

с небольшими изменениями:

js:

```
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
      var dot, eventDoc, doc, body, pageX, pageY;
      
      event = event || window.event; // IE-ism
      if (event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null) {
        eventDoc = (event.target && event.target.ownerDocument) || document;
        doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
        body = eventDoc.body;

        event.pageX = event.clientX +
          (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) -
          (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
        event.pageY = event.clientY +
          (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) -
          (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0 );
      }

      // Add a dot to follow the cursor
      dot = document.createElement('div');
      dot.className = "dot";
      dot.style.left = event.pageX + "px";
      dot.style.top = event.pageY + "px";
      document.body.appendChild(dot);
    }
  })();
```

css:

```
.dot {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
}
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/VladimirNT1/m3pdubwh/8/

Answer (score -1):

используй canvas(https://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/risuem-krug-dvizhuschiysya-vsled-za-kursorom-myshi.html)здесь круг замени на што хочеш(https://pcvector.net/codepen/694-oblachnyj-sled-ot-kursora-na-kanvase.html)или как здесь