# Помогите разобраться с canvas анимацией курсора

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Я взял код отсюда [Как сделать тепловой след от курсора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/874928/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0). Автором являюсь не я. Я хочу улучшить производительность данного холста. Как я понял чем больше canvas тем больше нагрузка на ПК. Извиняюсь если что то неправильно я начинающий разработчик. Так вот я нашел решение. Я сделал canvas с фиксированной позицией, шириной и высотой равной именно окну браузера. Я заметил что чем меньше размер canvas тем меньше нагрузка. Но почему-то canvas не работает когда скролл проходит ниже высоты окна браузера ( то есть и высоты canvas). Данный курсор работает корректно только в том случае когда высота canvas равна высоте всей страницы, но почему он не работает правильно с position: fixed; и высотой равной высоте окна браузера. В коде я показал те поля что поменял, остальной код схож с тем что сделал автор.  Вопрос таков: Почему ломается canvas при скролле равном дальше высоты окна браузера? Я ведь задал position: fixed;

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = window.innerWidth; // Вот тут 
var height = window.innerHeight; // Вот тут
var points = [];
var t = 0;

var radius = 50;
var period = 1000;
var color = "rgba(239, 91, 59, 0.5)";
var blur = 50;

canvas.style.width = canvas.width = width;
canvas.style.height = canvas.height = height;
context.fillStyle = color;
var filter = context.filter = "blur(" + blur + "px)";
var dr = radius / period;

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, document.body.offsetWidth, document.body.offsetHeight); // Вот тут
  let i = 0;
  let deleted = 0;
  let dt = -t + (t = window.performance.now());
  context.beginPath();
  while (i++ < points.length-1) {
    let p = points[i];
    let r = radius - (p[2] += dt) * dr;
    context.moveTo(p[0], p[1]);
    if (p[2] <= period) context.arc(p[0], p[1], r, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
    else deleted = i;
  }
    context.fill();
    points.splice(0, deleted);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);   
}

window.onmousemove = function(event) {
    points.push([event.pageX, event.pageY, 0]);
}

t = window.performance.now();
window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
body{ 
  height: 500vh; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding:0; 
  background: black;
}
```

```html
 
 <canvas id="canvas" style="position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;">Не поддерживается</canvas> <!-- Тут изменил на position: fixed; -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свойство события мыши `pageX, pageY` учитывает в себе прокрутку. Т.к. холст у Вас все время стоит на месте, то необходимо взять координаты относительно окна `event.x, event.y`

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = window.innerWidth; // Вот тут 
var height = window.innerHeight; // Вот тут
var points = [];
var t = 0;

var radius = 50;
var period = 1000;
var color = "rgba(239, 91, 59, 0.5)";
var blur = 50;

canvas.style.width = canvas.width = width;
canvas.style.height = canvas.height = height;
context.fillStyle = color;
var filter = context.filter = "blur(" + blur + "px)";
var dr = radius / period;

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, document.body.offsetWidth, document.body.offsetHeight); // Вот тут
  let i = 0;
  let deleted = 0;
  let dt = -t + (t = window.performance.now());
  context.beginPath();
  while (i++ < points.length-1) {
    let p = points[i];
    let r = radius - (p[2] += dt) * dr;
    context.moveTo(p[0], p[1]);
    if (p[2] <= period) context.arc(p[0], p[1], r, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
    else deleted = i;
  }
    context.fill();
    points.splice(0, deleted);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);   
}

window.onmousemove = function(event) {
    points.push([event.x, event.y, 0]);
}

t = window.performance.now();
window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
body{ 
  height: 500vh; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding:0; 
  background: black;
}
```

```html
 
 <canvas id="canvas" style="position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;">Не поддерживается</canvas> <!-- Тут изменил на position: fixed; -->
```

Comment: Хорошее решение (+), но не масштабируемое. При открывании на полный экран, работает только верхний левый [квандрант](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82#:~:text=%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%CC%81%D0%BD%D1%82%3A%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%3A,%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%B2%2090%C2%B0%2C%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0)

Comment: Большое вам спасибо! Очень вам благодарен. Не могли бы вы как разработчик посоветовать  где лучше всего можно изучить javascript? Я только только начал изучать его.

Comment: @БахтиярУмутбаев У вас ещё есть возможность поблагодарить с помощью `upvote` отвечающего.  Изучать `javascript` можно по учебнику Ильи Кантора https://learn.javascript.ru/size-and-scroll, а  ещё более быстрый метод - выбрать тег https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript и разбирать готовые решения. На примерах изучается быстрее